# Combining beeswarm with scalePoint

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to create a kind of categorical beeswarm plot where my observations (circles) are arranged by year on the x axis and also categorically by type on the y axis. I personally find `.scalePoint()` easier to work with, but I'm beginning to think I might not be able to use it for this particular application. Here is my code:

```js
var margins = {top:20, bottom:300, left:30, right:100};

var height = 400;
var width = 1000;

var totalWidth = width+margins.left+margins.right;
var totalHeight = height+margins.top+margins.bottom;

var svg = d3.select('body')
.append('svg')
.attr('width', totalWidth)
.attr('height', totalHeight);

var graphGroup = svg.append('g')
.attr('transform', "translate("+margins.left+","+margins.top+")");

var xScale = d3.scalePoint()
    .range([0, width]);






var data = [

{'year':'2002', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'im'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'im'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'qdlp'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'qdlp'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'qdlp'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'qdlp'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'qdlp'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'qdlp'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'im'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'im'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'im'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'im'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'im'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'im'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'im'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'im'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'im'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'im'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'im'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'im'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'qdlp'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'qdlp'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'qdlp'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'qdlp'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'qdlp'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'qdlp'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'qdlp'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'qdlp'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'qdlp'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'qdlp'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'qdlp'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'qdlp'}
];


  var colorScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range(["#e7eef8","#003366"]);



  xScale.domain(['','2002','2013','2016','2017','2018','2019']);

var colorMap = {
  'ia':"#003366",
  'im':"#b8cce4",
  'qdlp':"#4f81b9"
};

var yScale = d3.scalePoint()
.range([height,0])
.domain(['','ia','im','qdlp']);



  data.forEach(function (d) {
d.x = xScale(d.year);
d.y = yScale(d.type);
  });

  var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(data)
.force("x", d3.forceX(function(d) {
  return xScale(d.year);
}).strength(0.05))
.force("y", d3.forceY(function(d) {
  return yScale(d.type);
}).strength(0.1))
.force("collide", d3.forceCollide(4).iterations(1))
.stop();

for (var i = 0; i < 484; ++i) {
  simulation.tick();
  data.forEach(function (d) {
if (d.type) {
  d.y = yScale(d.y);
} else {
  d.y = yScale(d.y);
}
  });
}

  graphGroup.append("g")
.attr("class", "axis axis--x")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
.call(d3.axisBottom(xScale));

graphGroup.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + 0 + ")")
  .call(d3.axisRight(yScale));

  var circles = graphGroup.selectAll(null)
.data(data)
.enter()
.append("circle")
.attr("r", 3)
.attr("cx", function(d) {
  return d.x;
})
.attr("cy", function(d) {
  return d.y;
})
.style('fill', function(d) {return colorMap[d.type] });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

You will notice all of my circles are assigned to the same y value. Not only are there no circles appended to the other two categories, there are no beeswarm cluster groups at all. For some reason, all the circles are appended on top of each other.

I was expecting them to be arranged in a beeswarm manner based on their x & y coordinates. For example, 2002 should just have one circle; 2013 should have a cluster of 44 at `yScale('ia')`, a cluster of 2 at `yScale('im')` and a cluster of 6 at `yScale('qdlp')`, and so forth for all years.

But again, that did not pan out, and I'm not sure why.

### Question

How should I adjust my visual to allow for separate swarms that have a center based on d3's `.scalePoint()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `d3.scalePoint` is the best choice for the task, no doubt about it.

Back to the question, this piece of code running after each tick...

```
data.forEach(function (d) {
  if (d.type) {
    d.y = yScale(d.y);
  } else {
    d.y = yScale(d.y);
  }
});
```

...not only is overriding the simulation, but even worse, you're passing a number to the point scale that has strings as the domain.

The solution could not be simpler: just remove it.

```js
var margins = {top:20, bottom:300, left:30, right:100};

var height = 400;
var width = 1000;

var totalWidth = width+margins.left+margins.right;
var totalHeight = height+margins.top+margins.bottom;

var svg = d3.select('body')
.append('svg')
.attr('width', totalWidth)
.attr('height', totalHeight);

var graphGroup = svg.append('g')
.attr('transform', "translate("+margins.left+","+margins.top+")");

var xScale = d3.scalePoint()
    .range([0, width]);






var data = [

{'year':'2002', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'im'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'im'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'qdlp'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'qdlp'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'qdlp'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'qdlp'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'qdlp'},
{'year':'2013', 'type':'qdlp'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'ia'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'im'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'im'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'im'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'im'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'im'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'im'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'im'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'im'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'im'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'im'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'im'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'im'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'qdlp'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'qdlp'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'qdlp'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'qdlp'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'qdlp'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'qdlp'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'qdlp'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'qdlp'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'qdlp'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'qdlp'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'qdlp'},
{'year':'2016', 'type':'qdlp'}
];


  var colorScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range(["#e7eef8","#003366"]);



  xScale.domain(['','2002','2013','2016','2017','2018','2019']);

var colorMap = {
  'ia':"#003366",
  'im':"#b8cce4",
  'qdlp':"#4f81b9"
};

var yScale = d3.scalePoint()
.range([height,0])
.domain(['','ia','im','qdlp']);



  data.forEach(function (d) {
d.x = xScale(d.year);
d.y = yScale(d.type);
  });

  var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(data)
.force("x", d3.forceX(function(d) {
  return xScale(d.year);
}).strength(0.05))
.force("y", d3.forceY(function(d) {
  return yScale(d.type);
}).strength(0.1))
.force("collide", d3.forceCollide(4).iterations(1))
.stop();

for (var i = 0; i < 484; ++i) {
  simulation.tick();
}

  graphGroup.append("g")
.attr("class", "axis axis--x")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
.call(d3.axisBottom(xScale));

graphGroup.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + 0 + ")")
  .call(d3.axisRight(yScale));

  var circles = graphGroup.selectAll(null)
.data(data)
.enter()
.append("circle")
.attr("r", 3)
.attr("cx", function(d) {
  return d.x;
})
.attr("cy", function(d) {
  return d.y;
})
.style('fill', function(d) {return colorMap[d.type] });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```